# OpenWhisk build failure in local vagrant

Tags: vagrant, couchdb, openwhisk

Attempting to build my local [openwhisk](https://github.com/openwhisk/openwhisk) instance using the provided VagrantFile. I am using the ephemeral CouchDB container as my datasource.

During `ant clean build deploy` I get the following exceptions:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/vagrant/openwhisk/build.xml:55: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/vagrant/openwhisk/build.xml:99: exec returned: 5
```

Further up the logs I see the following repeated under the installCatalog.sh section: 
`[exec] error: The supplied authentication is invalid`

I've verified that the couchdb credentials in my `cloudant-local.env` are correct by executing some test curl commands. Not sure what other authentication credentials it could be complaining about. Any ideas?

http://dumptext.com/6QDOWNE3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use an ephemeral Couch instance, you need to start it after `ant clean build` and before `deploy`. Further, every time you start the container, you have to run the script `tools/db/createImmortalDBs.sh` to initialize the authentication store.

```
ant clean build
tools/db/couchdb/start-couchdb-box.sh ...
tools/db/createImmortalDBs.sh
ant deploy
```

BTW, Did you mean `couchdb-local.env`?

Comment: I'll try that now. Yes, should have been `couchdb-local.env` - thanks

Comment: Ok, that was my issue. I was running `ant clean build deploy` in one step and I guess `ant clean` was killing the ephemeral couchdb instance? 

Once I followed the path above everything operates as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Great - `ant clean` tears down all the container including Couch. Will make it clearer in the docs.